# Cocoa method naming convention: With vs For

Tags: cocoa, naming-conventions

I am looking for a general consensus or opinions on With vs For as in things like:

```
-(NSImage *)imageWithStyle:(MyImageStyle)style
-(NSImage *)imageForStyle:(MyImageStyle)style

-(id)controllerWithView:(NSView *)view
-(id)controllerForView:(NSView *)view
```

Thoughts?

When you use one over the other and why?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to work on the basis that if A has no relation to B, but aspects of B might change what A will do, then you're making an A *with* information from B.

If A has some relation to B, e.g. B has a way of listing all the A's that are associated with it, then I'll be making an A *for* (on behalf of) B.

The controller is a good example. If it's a controller being made *with* a view, it implies that the controller isn't "for" anything, it's just some controller, but it's using bits or all of a view to do Things. But if it's a controller *for* a view, then now we've implied a permanent association - this is a controller that is for, i.e. that controls, the view. So here, I'd use `controllerForView`.

In the image and style example, I imagine your intent is that some object describes default aspects of the images being built. I'd use `imageWithStyle`. Everyone likes an image with style... `;-)`

It's subtle either way though. You could consider less conventional but clearer terms if you think there is ambiguity - e.g `imageFromTemplate` or `imageBasedOnStyle`. Cocoa tends to be more about almost-English legibility and less about being terse.